# Windows 10 XAMPP suddenly very slow

Tags: windows, xampp

I've been running a script on my computer (custom made web-based POS) for about a year now on XAMPP and windows 10. All of a sudden as of last Friday I've noticed things have becoming increasingly slow. To the point where a simple page that does nothing but connect to mysql and run a simple query (this query when run via phpmyadmin runs in <20 ms) takes over 5 seconds to load the page.

I've made no changes to the config and I've tried everything I could find online:

[WAMP/XAMPP is responding very slow over localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432601/wamp-xampp-is-responding-very-slow-over-localhost)
[XAMPP Running really slowly with PHP/MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196009/xampp-running-really-slowly-with-php-mysql)
[PHP on Windows with XAMPP running 100 times too slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36754293/php-on-windows-with-xampp-running-100-times-too-slow)
[XAMPP / WAMP / whatever it is: Apache is running super slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148131/xampp-wamp-whatever-it-is-apache-is-running-super-slow)

I'm pulling out my hair, what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

If it's still an issue, for me it was the G-Data Security Client that comes with a server side security (maybe it's in other G-Data Versions as well). It has an option to read Website Data on port 80 and 443. Unfortunately you can't exclude webpages from it so you have to disable it completely.